# Why are CSS rules with namespace-prefixed selectors not being applied to XSLT output?

Tags: css, xml, xslt, xhtml, xml-namespaces

I use namespaces to identify the HTML fragments that could be sent from different users, but Internet Explorer does not support a content type XHTML+XML, the solution below being suggested to me, the problem is that the CSS rules whose selectors have a namespace prefix are ignored... I don't know why? just I want to mention that i'm new to XSL, so one by one please :)

index.php

```
<?php header('Content-type: application/xml'); ?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xslt.xsl"?>

<html xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:aa="zz" 
      xmlns:ee="rr">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        aa\:p{background: #00ff00;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <aa:p>aaa</aa:p>
    <ee:p>aaa</ee:p>
</body>
</html>
```

xslt.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
              doctype-system=" http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">
      <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet')" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You don't need the rule to remove the `<?xml-stylesheet` PI. It is not passed along into the XSLT processor.

Answer (score 0):

This "*issue*" has nothing to do with xslt (at leased in the first place). If the css is not doing what you are expecting you have to consider the html (which is generated by your xslt).
Because you are removing any namespaces prefixes there is not manespaces prefix in your generated hmtl.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" " http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            aa\:p{background: #00ff00;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>aaa</p>
        <p>aaa</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

But the css content is only text from xslt point of view. Thererfore change this `<style>` in your input XML to:

```
 <style type="text/css">
       p{background: #00ff00;}
    </style>
```

Or you have to do text processing with xst (what is a little more complex with xslt-1.0).

Comment: ok thanks, i think i'll use the second proposition, XST even if i don't know what's that mean :) it has a relation with Cross Site Tracing?

Comment: Sorry but, this does not sound as you do know what your are doing at all. Your css does not match your html. You have somehow to remove the  namespace prefix ("aa/" in your example) form the css. But I do not think this will work well on the long therm (for more complex css).

Comment: I worked a lot on this topic until forgetting the basics, and becoming stupid, you've just wake me up :) thanks...